# Oración condicional con que y con si - hay una diferencia semántica?

Tags: subjuntivo, condicional

¿Hay diferencias semánticas entre las frases siguientes?

**Me sorprendería que mis padres dijeran que no.**

y

**Me sorprendería si mis padres dijeran que no.**

Espero que al menos ambas sean correctos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Ambas significan lo mismo. Y ambas frases son correctas. Otra opción, igualmente válida, es

> Me sorprendería que mis padres dijesen que no.

o bien

> Me sorprendería si mis padres dijesen que no.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta. :)